# Round corner button: Where am I wrong

Tags: android-layout, android

I want to create **round corner** button. This is what I tried:

I have defined the button's background drawable **button_bg.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_enabled="false"
        android:drawable="@color/grey">

        <shape>
          <solid
              android:color="#ef4444" />
          <stroke
              android:width="1dp"
              android:color="#992f2f" />
          <corners
              android:radius="16dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>


    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@color/dark_grey"
    >
        <shape>
          <solid
              android:color="#ef4444" />
          <stroke
              android:width="1dp"
              android:color="#992f2f" />
          <corners
              android:radius="16dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>


    <item
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@color/blue"
    >
        <shape>
          <solid
              android:color="#ef4444" />
          <stroke
              android:width="1dp"
              android:color="#992f2f" />
          <corners
              android:radius="16dp" />
        </shape>

    </item>
</selector>
```

Then, I apply it to my button in layout file:

```
<Button
      android:text="@string/press_me"
      android:layout_margin="12dp"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="30dp"

      android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
/>
```

But my button is still showing sharp corner instead of the round one, why??

(Please **don't just throw me a link** about how to make round corner, my above code followed those tutorials, I just want to know where am I wrong. Thanks)

Comment: you are wrong in that you dont say what the resulr of your code is

Comment: My result is a sharp corner instead of round one.

Comment: try to remove android:drawable="@color/*"

Comment: i tried it myself and removing android:drawable="" works  like @pskink said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `android:drawable` from the item node have it like this.

```
 <item  android:state_pressed="true"
        android:state_enabled="true">
```

EDIT :  (How can I specify the color from colors.xml for item then?)

Create a stateful color drawable for your button text color.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:color="#ffffff" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#000000" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#000000" />
    <item android:color="#ffffff" />
</selector>
```

and then set this as your text color for your button .

```
android:textColor="@drawable/button_text_color"
```

Comment: How can I specify the color from colors.xml for item then?

Comment: You need to create a stateful color for your button just like you created a stateful background. Editing to add this.

Answer (score 1):

Remove all `android:drawable` from `item` as below then it will work.

When you add the attribute `android:drawable` in `item` then this drawable overlapped your created shape. That's why you can't see your rounded shape.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_enabled="false"><shape>
            <solid android:color="#ef4444" />

            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#992f2f" />

            <corners android:radius="16dp" />
        </shape></item>
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="true"><shape>
            <solid android:color="#ef4444" />

            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#992f2f" />

            <corners android:radius="16dp" />
        </shape></item>
    <item android:state_enabled="true"><shape>
            <solid android:color="#ef4444" />

            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#992f2f" />

            <corners android:radius="16dp" />
        </shape></item>

</selector>
```

Comment: How can I specify the color from colors.xml for item then?

Comment: in This line `<solid android:color="#ef4444" />`...change color as your wish.

Comment: Do you mean there is no way to directly get color from colors.xml resource in this scenario?

Comment: I can't find it any way...may be its not possible.